# Need to change default text on Credit Card area

Tags: wordpress, payment-processor, contribution-page

I am using civi 4.7.29 on wordpress 4.9.1
Please see the screen shot.  I am using PayPal Payments Pro and I need to remove or change the marked lines.  Can you tell me which file to edit?
Also I would like to change the color of the Contribute button if possible. If anyone knows where I can do that, please let me know.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to:
Administer => customize Data and Screens => Word Replacements

This should do the trick.

Also please try the same for "Contribute" it will work but this will replace all the contribute buttons - so please test it

[image]

I guess this helps !!!

Thanks

Comment: That took care of the part I wanted removed, but did nothing for the paragraph above. Do you know where the files are so I can modify them manually?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modify the files - which will break on every CiviCRM upgrade - consider instead hiding them with CSS or Javascript.  You can load custom CSS by specifiying the URL in **Administer » System Settings » Resource URLs**.  [JavaScript injection](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/) requires writing an extension.